# How to run node "REPL" Module that syncs certain variables to the main context?

Tags: javascript, node.js, virtual-machine, read-eval-print-loop

I was working on my new project, It's kinda like pm that manages multiple node instance
I am using [REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) module, I have some commands
However there is 1 command that push a value to an array to tell a listener, but it doesnt push that value to the global array, is there a way to sync that array from REPL context to the main context?

I tried setting `useGlobal` to true in the option

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html), The default evaluator provides access to any variables that exist in the global scope. It is possible to expose a variable to the REPL explicitly by assigning it to the `context` object associated with each `REPLServer`:

```
const repl = require('node:repl');
const arr = [];

repl.start('> ').context.m = arr;
```

(Not tested)

Comment: I am trying to retrieve variable from it, or make repl do change directly to my variable.